# Preposition for "autre" and "différent"

Tags: prépositions, comparatifs

"I usually eat at a different restaurant than him" ("him" refers to another person).

> D'habitude, je mange dans un autre restaurant ___ lui.
>
> D'habitude, je mange dans un différent restaurant ___ lui.

Which propositions can we use in the two sentences? Is it correct that we can use *de* or *que* in the first sentence, but only *de* in the second sentence?

Comment: D'habitude, je mange dans un autre restaurant.

Comment: Vous devriez préciser qu'est censé représenter "lui" dans vos phrases. Si c'est à la place de"restaurant" ce n'est pas correct, on doit utliser celui-ci ou celui-là, si c'est à la place de quelqu'un la réponse est "que": Je mange dans un autre restaurant que lui (meaning , I don't go to the same restaurant as this person)

Comment: @P.O. C'est en effet à la place de quelqu'un. J'ai modifié la question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour la première phrase, j'emploierai « que » et pas « de » :

> D'habitude, je mange dans un autre restaurant **que** lui.

Pour la seconde phrase, c'est le contraire, « de » et pas « que » :

> D'habitude, je mange dans un restaurant différent **de** lui.

Comment: Merci ! Pour la seconde phrase, il n'est pas possible de dire "... dans un **différent restaurant** de lui" ?

Comment: @user11550:On peut mettre l'adjectif avant mais il est plus agréable à l'oreille de le mettre après.

Answer (score 1):

The reflexive  personnal pronoun "lui" you use to qualify the restaurant isn't correct.
A restaurant is a thing (not alive): you should use the composed form of masculine singular demonstrative pronoun : "celui-ci" or "celui-là".

You can only use the preposition "que" in the first sentence and "de" in the second while keeping the same meaning. 
If you use "de", the sentence could become for example: "D'habitude, je mange dans un autre restaurant de Paris."

Comment: "lui" actually refers to a restaurant. I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

Avec?
D'habitude, je mange dans un autre restaurant avec lui.
D'habitude, avec lui, je mange dans un autre restaurant / dans un restaurant différent.
Attention! Il faut dire 'dans un autre restaurant' ou 'dans un 'restaurant différent'.  Il est impossible de dire 'un différent restaurant'.

Comment: "lui" est à la place d'une personne. J'ai modifié la question.